# Problema Matrices de objetos dinamicos

Tags: c++

Estoy trabajando con matrices de objetos dinamicos y el problema es que necesito ingresar un objeto habitacion a una matriz pero solo agrega al primer espacio de la matriz en otras palabras al espacio matriz[0][0] si alguien me puede ayudar con eso se lo agradezco, dejo el codigo para que lo analicen gracias..

//Esta es la estructura de la matriz

```
Matriz::Matriz(int f, int c) : filas(f), columna(c) {
    matriz = new Habitacion** [filas]; // Columna Filas
    for (int i = 0; i < filas; i++)
        matriz[i] = new Habitacion* [columna];

    for (int i = 0; i < filas; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < columna; j++)
           matriz[i][j] = NULL;
}
```

// Este es el metodo que necesito

```
bool Matriz::RegistroCLiente(Habitacion* hab) {
    for (int i = 0; i < filas; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < columna; j++)
            if (matriz[i][j] == NULL) {
                matriz[i][j] = hab;
                return true;
            }
            else
                return false;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tu problema está en la posición del `else`.
Tal y como lo tienes, solo realiza **1** comparación:

- si `== NULL`, coloca el valor.
- En otro caso, haces un `return false`, por lo que ya **no se realizan mas comparaciones**.

Basta con eliminar el `else` para permitir seguir buscando, y retornar `false` **fuera de ambos `for`**:

```
bool Matriz::RegistroCLiente( Habitacion* hab ) {
    for( int i = 0; i < filas; i++ ) {
        for( int j = 0; j < columna; j++ ) {
            if( matriz[i][j] == NULL ) {
                matriz[i][j] = hab;
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Gracias crack, soy nuevo en esto y no tenia la menor idea